# Сайт коряво отображается в IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Во всех браузерах сайт отображается нормально, в IE никак не получается вывести его. Помогите пожалуйста! http://евнат.рф

Comment: не новость)

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы корректно отображалось в ИЕ нужно создавать отдельные стили для него, браузер сам по себе пришибленый по этому тут никто я думаю писать их не будет. Конечно же лучше всего обратиться к фрилансерам которые сделают это за Вас.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Либо писать css, либо вообще забить на отображение сайта в IE..

Answer (score 1):

Во всех современных браузерах стоят хоть и различные движки, но метод обработки страниц у всех сходен(кроме IE). Так, разработчики IE, например, решили обрабатывать JS-код по своему методу, DOM-модель документа тоже строится по уникальному методу. Если писать сайт только для IE, то их метод даже может показаться удобным, но, к сожалению, не кроссбраузерным...да, IE, как и все последние версии браузеров, поддерживает HTML5 и CSS3, но, как писал выше, метод построения страницы свойственный только IE.  Так, что надо лишь надеяться лишь на то, что разработчики решат в будущем тотально переработать свой энджин =)